# Regex help for git commit messages

Tags: regex, string, gitlab, pattern-matching, regex-lookarounds

I want to create a regex to enforce git commit messages. The styles are as follows:

```
<type>(<scope>): <subject>

<body>

BREAKING CHANGE: <breaking>

Refs: <references>
```

Subject to the following conditions:

1. (<scope>) is optional.
2. can be multi-lined with paragraphs and should match only till before BREAKING CHANGE/Refs.
3. is optional.

The issue is:
3. BREAKING CHANGE and Refs are optional and thus body would have to match to the end if and only if the two did not exist.

My current regex:

```
/
(?<type>feat|fix|docs|style|refactor|perf|test|chore) -> Type

(?<scope>\(.+\))?: (?<subject>.{3,50}) -> Scope and Subject

(?:(?:\n\n(?<body>[\w\W]{3,}))? -> Body (how to match until the end, or stop if it sees BREAKING CHANGE or Refs?)

(?:\n\nBREAKING CHANGE: (?<breaking> [\w\W]{3,}))?

(?:\n\nRefs: (?<footer> [\w\W]{3,}))?
/gm
```

Is this possible? I'm trying to use named captures to extract the different parts of a commit message while also testing its validity.

Examples are as follows of good commit messages:

```
feat(stuff): add feature

Body text and stuff
Multiline body
```

```
feat(stuff): add feature

Body text and stuff
Multiline body

BREAKING CHANGE: Some breaking thing
```

```
feat(stuff): add feature

Body text and stuff
Multiline body

Refs: Closes issue #270
```

Comment: Can `BREAKING CHANGE:` and `Refs:` also be multiline? Try it like this https://regex101.com/r/YCSaPm/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird Yes, they can be multi-lined as well. I ended up going with https://regex101.com/r/n7M4tw/1 as Gitlab does not allow for lookaheads/lookbehinds. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up going with the following as Gitlab does not allow for lookaheads/lookbehinds. This allows for arbitrarily long bodies as well as key: value footers.

```
^(?:Initial commit\.?|Merge [^\r\n]+|(?P<type>build|chore|ci|docs|feat|fix|perf|refactor|revert|style|test)(?:\((?P<scope>[\w-]+)\))?(?P<breaking>!)?: (?P<desc>.{3,50})(?P<body>[\w\s,'.`\[\]-]+)?(?P<footer>(?:\n(?:(?:[\w\s-]+): (?:[\w\s -`]+))+)|$))
```

Note that this regex is for [Gitlab compatible RE2](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax).

Test it here: [regex101.com/r/n7M4tw/1](https://regex101.com/r/n7M4tw/1)